# unauthorized with sendgrid smtp

Tags: reactjs, sendgrid

I'm sending emails using sendgrid smtp and always get unauthorized error for the request.
I followed the docs here https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/api-getting-started/.
Should I login in from my terminal or something like this?

```
 const sendFunc = () => {
        return fetch('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send', {
            method: 'Post',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer {my apiKey-here}'
            },
            data: { "personalizations": [{ "to": [{ "email": "mahmoudnafea19@gmail.com", "name": "John Doe" }], "subject": "Hello, World!" }], "content": [{ "type": "text/plain", "value": "Heya!" }], "from": { "email": "mahmoud.m.elsayed19@gmail.com", "name": "Sam Smith" }, "reply_to": { "email": "sam.smith@example.com", "name": "Sam Smith" } }
        }).then((response) => console.log(response)).catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }
```

Comment: i would list what you followed in the docs exactly, and link it. By the way does it need to be send in grid? Or are you just trying to send email from your react app

Comment: yeah I have to use sendgrid. the docs https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/api-getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

I had to pass the data and headers as objects outside the function call